# What is some books at the level which including this inequality and its proof?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I always wanting to looking into harder random variable/probability/stochastic process/statistics books
that are harder than the intro one and have multiple random variable but easy enough to have include this inequality which is multiple-variable Chebyshev's inequality

$P\left[ \sum_{ i = 1 }^n \frac{ ( X_i - \mu_i )^2 }{ \sigma_i^2 t_i^2 } \ge k^2 \right] \le \frac{ 1 }{ k^2 } \sum_{ i = 1 }^n \frac{ 1 }{ t_i^2 }$

Comment: I am not sure if it has the problem you mention as I don't have my copy handy, but you might want to check out "Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes" by A. Papoulis. It is used in many graduate schools.

Comment: There is *nothing* "multiple variable" about the inequality you give. It's a *direct* application of the standard Markov's inequality. If you can clarify what your question is (e.g., to know what *harder* means we need to know what you're already looking at. Also, what do you consider *intro*?) and add a little more detail, I think it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I  THINK,  THIS COULD BE USEFUL FOR YOU](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-31/issue-4/Multivariate-Chebyshev-Inequalities/10.1214/aoms/1177705673.full)

[SEE  THIS ALSO, BY  Dr. D.N. LAL](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/25048251)

Comment: $\large \textbf{PLEASE DON'T YELL!!}$